# Correct z coordinates of a walk cycle

Tags: actions

I made a walk cycle. I use it in NLA editor. I noticed that the character is too high (3 inch above the ground ). I tried to correct this using a variety of ways:

A) I Went to the graph editor and locked every curve except the Z coordinate and then : G-Y -0.1 to lower the Z curves.

The character exploded.

B) I tried to select all the bones and add keys frames with the right altitude but it will add a crazy number of useless Keyframes.

C) I could parent the character and lower it only during the walk.

Every time I use the walk :(

Is there an efficient way to do this (outside of re-making my Walk Cycle)?

Thanks!

Comment: if this is a walk cycle, you need to select the armature, stay in Object mode, go in the Graph Editor, lock every track except Z Location and move on the Y axis. If this doesn't work maybe share your file so that we can test: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Thanks. But won't lower every part of the animation, including the non walking strips ? In fact I need to lower the Walk strip only.

Comment: Thanks, but lowering the root bone in Edit mode will lower the whole character in every strip of my animation.  In fact I need to lower the Walk strip only.

Comment: Actually I meant moving the root in Pose mode, in Edit mode it would not change anything, but perhaps share your file (armature only)?